# Django Templates: Render a dictionary object stored in a context object?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

In Django I have a dictionary object like this:

```
car = {
  'color': 'red',
  'doors': 4
}
```

I would like to store this dictionary in an Django ORM Model class like so:

```
class Things(models.Model):
  car = models.TextField()
  ... other fields
```

My template is a view for `Things`.  Is it possible to access values for `car` in the template a way such as this:

```
Car color: {{ things_object.car.color }}
```

Note, it is not a requirement to use `TextField` to save the `car` dictionary.

Comment: you can create a class for the Car and reference it using a foreign key, or if u want to store it as a string you can use json.encode and json.decode.

Comment: @Kassab for several reasons, in this application, a separate Car table isn't practical.  Could you elaborate on the json.encode/decode solution?  How would that work in the template?

Comment: Have a look at [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) in the django documentation.

Comment: as @dgw said, JSONField may provide what you are looking for. check this example (https://oak-tree.tech/blog/django31-json-field)